# Swift Convert type

Tags: json, swift

I need to parse JSON file. Here is my getJSON func

```
public var shops: NSArray = []
public func getShop() {    
let url = NSURL (string: "http://urltojson.com")    
let data = NSData (contentsOfURL: url!)    
shops = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options: .AllowFragments) as! NSArray        
}
```

and here is how I get data from JSON

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let test = shops ["Titile"] as? String
    print(test)
}
```

The problem is when I run my code it shows me an error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type Int"
so, If I change ["Titile"] in `let test = shops ["Titile"]` for any Int, e.g. [8] `let test = shops [8] as? String` it works. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please post the actual JSON received?

Answer (score 1):

looks like your variable "shops" is an array which takes an index as an integer instead of a dictionary which takes a key as a String.

```
//here shops is an array of strings
var shops:[String] = ["dog","cat","pig","cow"]
//shops[2] is equal to "pig"

//here shops is a dictionary of string keys and string values
var shops:[String:String] = ["animal1":"dog","animal2":"cat","animal3":"pig","animal4":"cow"]
//shops["animal2"] is equal to "cat"
```

Comment: Yeah. Forgot to mention my variable. It's public var shops: NSArray = []
How to convert it to [String] type?

Comment: var shops:[String:<whatever type it holds>] = []